# Non Intersecting two ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, resultset

I have two result sets coming from two different database and I need to compare it. I want an operation like

> A-B

to be performed on them.

I cannot perform row by row comparison as 1st row in A resultset can be present anywhere in B resultset.

Below is the code to do that in .NET, which is very easy and perfect .

```
var nonIntersecting = dtSource.AsEnumerable().Except
                      (
                        dtTarget.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default
                      );
try
{
   dtSrcToTgtResult = nonIntersecting.CopyToDataTable();
} catch (InvalidOperationException ex) {}
```

Here dtSource,dtTarget are datatables having source and target data from databases.
dtSrcToTgtResult contains data present in source but not in target, which is exactly what I want.

Can same be done in JavaScript with result sets. I can also check `CachedRowSet` or `webRowSet` if something like this is available in it.

**EDIT**

For people who are giving minus votes. this is what i already did, but its not solving the problem.

```
private Boolean compare(ResultSet rsSrc,ResultSet rsTgt,String ExecCondition)
    {
        Boolean status = true;
        try  
        {
            ResultSetMetaData metaSrc = rsSrc.getMetaData(); 
            ResultSetMetaData metaTgt = rsTgt.getMetaData();
            final int columnCountSrc = metaSrc.getColumnCount();
            List<DBRow> dList = new  ArrayList<DBRow>();
            List<DBRow> DataInSourceNotInTarget = new ArrayList<DBRow>();
            List<DBRow> DataInTargetNotInSource = new ArrayList<DBRow>();

            DBRow d = new DBRow();
            DBRow d1 = new DBRow();

            for (int column = 1; column <= columnCountSrc; column++) 
            {
            d.Row.add(metaSrc.getColumnName(column));
            d1.Row.add(metaTgt.getColumnName(column));
            }
            DataInSourceNotInTarget.add(d);
            DataInTargetNotInSource.add(d1);

            if(ExecCondition.equals("Source To Target"))
            {

            while(rsSrc.next())
            {

                if(rsTgt.next())
                {
                for (int column = 1; column <= columnCountSrc; column++) 
                {

                    Object valueSrc = rsSrc.getObject(column);
                    Object valueTgt = rsTgt.getObject(column);

                        if(!valueSrc.toString().equals(valueTgt.toString()))
                        {
                            status=false;
                            System.out.println("ValueSRC: "+v    alueSrc.toString());
                            System.out.println("ValueTgt: "+valueTgt.toString());
                    }

            }
            }
            else
            {
                // if target rows ends
                DBRow dr = new DBRow();

                for (int column = 1; column <= columnCountSrc; column++) 
                {

                    Object valueSrc = rsSrc.getObject(column);
                    dr.Row.add(valueSrc);
                }
                DataInSourceNotInTarget.add(dr);

            }

        }
    }//exec condition if


        if(ExecCondition.equals("Target To Source"))
        {

        while(rsTgt.next())
        {

            if(rsSrc.next())
            {
            for (int column = 1; column <= columnCountSrc; column++) 
            {

                Object valueSrc = rsSrc.getObject(column);
                Object valueTgt = rsTgt.getObject(column);

                    if(!valueSrc.toString().equals(valueTgt.toString()))
                    {
                        status=false;
                        System.out.println("ValueSRC: "+valueSrc.toString());
                        System.out.println("ValueTgt: "+valueTgt.toString());
                    }

            }
            }
            else
            {
                // if Source rows ends
                DBRow dr = new DBRow();

                for (int column = 1; column <= columnCountSrc; column++) 
                {

                    Object valueTgt = rsTgt.getObject(column);
                    dr.Row.add(valueTgt);
                }
                DataInTargetNotInSource.add(dr);

            }

        }

        for(DBRow obj:DataInTargetNotInSource)
        {
            obj.print();
        }
    }//exec condition if


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: how is the comparison done? is source and target have the same columns?

Comment: @sharonbn source and target will have same column but there could occur mismatches in data, thats y the validation. To determine whats in source but not in target.

Comment: you want others to do your homework?

Comment: @Despicable i have already coded but that is done comparing row by row. and that is not solving the problem. i already said that. why giving minus votes.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that is functional but not optimal:

1. It requires to load all rows into in-memory data structures (each ResultSet is loaded into list, each item is map of column name-value)
2. loop on source rows' list and for every item in that list - search that it does not exist in target list (meaning o(n^2) processing)

I used [Apache DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/index.html) to easily convert ResultSet to List.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapListHandler;

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)) {

    // load source table
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet sourceRs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM source");
    List<Map<String, Object>> sourceRows = new MapListHandler().handle(sourceRs);
    sourceRs.close();
    st.close();

    // load target table
    st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet targetRs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM target");
    List<Map<String, Object>> targetRows = new MapListHandler().handle(targetRs);
    targetRs.close();
    st.close();

    // for every row in source, look for no match in target
    List<Map<String, Object>> diffRows = 
    sourceRows.stream()
        .filter(sourceRow -> rowExistsInTable(sourceRow, targetRows) == false)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    diffRows.stream().forEach(System.out::println); 

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT:

you will notice that the filtering of `sourceRows` is now done according to result of method `rowExistsInTable()`. I added methods to search row in table and check rows' equality without relying on java 8 lambda syntax (also added as much documentation as I could :))

```
/**
 * checks if {@code searchRow} exists in {@code table}
 * existence is determined according to {@code areRowsEqual} method 
 * @param searchRow {@code Map<String, Object>} where keys are column names and values are column vales 
 * @param table {@code List} of {@code Map<String, Object>} rows 
 * @return {@code true} if {@code searchRow} was found in {@code table} 
 */
public static boolean rowExistsInTable(Map<String, Object> searchRow, List<Map<String, Object>> table)
{
    for (Map<String, Object> tableRow : table) {
        if (areRowsEqual(tableRow, searchRow)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * checks if all of row1 columns are found with same values in row2
 * note: does not check if there is column in row2 that does not exist in row1  
 * @param row1 
 * @param row2
 * @return {@code true} if {@code row1} is equal to {@code row2}
 */
public static boolean areRowsEqual(Map<String, Object> row1, Map<String, Object> row2)
{
    // loop on row1 columns
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> row1Column : row1.entrySet()) {
        String row1ColumnName = row1Column.getKey(); 
        Object row1ColumnValue = row1Column.getValue();
        // search row1 column in row2
        if (row2.containsKey(row1ColumnName) &&
            row2.get(row1ColumnName) != null &&
            row2.get(row1ColumnName).equals(row1ColumnValue)) {
            // row1 column was found in row2, nothing to do 
        } else {
            // row1 column was not found in row2
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;  // all row 1 columns found in row 2
}
```

Comment: i cant import java.util.stream.* in my app. and sourceRows.stream() is not available.

Comment: This is Java 8 feature. what version are you using?

Comment: the diffRows just  returns everything that is in the source

Comment: it means that you need to modify the comparison of rows. in my example I use `targetRow.equals(sourceRow)` to determine if a source row exists in the target resultset. it is based on the equals() of HashMap, which is supposed to check for equality of both keys and values. you may need to modify this according to the data that you have (maybe check only primary key columns?). printing and/or debugging is the next pahse...

Comment: i havent used lambda exp ever in my life. can you suggest me the modification to get difference of rows when compared from source to target.