# Is it possible to intersect two jdbc ResultSet objects

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

Is it possible to intersect two or more ResultSet-s and the result is again a ResultSet object.

I want to note that it is not possible for the task I implement at the moment to do that before(i.e. to modify sql select statement)

Comment: The best bet is to store the data from each `ResultSet` in a data structure, then merge these structures as you want/need.

Comment: Hope this will help.  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244960/non-intersecting-two-resultset-in-java
But in your case you have to do reverse

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that at the end I need Result Set object (the intersected one) as it is needed for custom implemented Cursors.

Comment: *need Result Set object (the intersected one) as it is needed for...* this is madness, whatever the reason you want/need a `ResultSet` with the merged data without changing the SQL statement. Do you know that you cannot add data in a `ResultSet` because it's not a proper object data structure, right, because it interacts directly with database? If you really need a `ResultSet`, you can merge the results, store them in a temporary table and then execute another select on this temp table just to have a `ResultSet`, but this is a really odd and ugly approach to follow.

Comment: I know, but this is a problem I actually have and I need to check what might be the best solution (if any)

Comment: What comes to mind is using, `JoinRowSet` .

Comment: @user3719857  Can you explain me more thoroughly what do you mean